# Regex not matching as expected in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Here's what I'm doing: I'm scraping some HTML from an external site using Simple HTML Dom, then I strip the spaces out, and I try to use a Regex to grab the information I need and put it into an array. This code was working perfectly until the external site modified their HTML and I had to come up with a new regex. I made a regex that seemed to capture everything I wanted (I used regexr.com), but for some reason it isn't working now that I plug it into my code. Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

require('../classes/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.***.com/');
$player_array = array();
foreach($html->find('table#herodev_list td') as $ele){
    $ele = $ele->innertext;
    $html_string = $html_string.$ele;
}
$html_string = str_replace(" ", "", $html_string);
$regex = '/(?<=/avatar/).+?(?=/)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $html_string, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $player){
    array_push($player_array, strtolower($player));
}
print_r($player_array);
```

The problem seems to lie in the preg_match_all - the matches array is empty so I'm assuming nothing was matched. Here is a sample of what $html_string usually looks like:

```
<imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/Kainzo/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/PuffinMuffin19/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/neows0/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/Sniped105/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/EJBomber26/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/GiantBeardedFace/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/Montelu/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/GreekCrackShot/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/Marcellinius/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/HelsEch/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/NZD2000/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/Mrchucklez/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/Dragondrakar/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/malita55/10.png"><imgsrc="http://minotar.net/avatar/Dazzlar/10.png">
```

My best guess is that PHP's regex engine differs somehow from Regexr or I'm just doing something stupid. It's been months since I originally wrote this app so its inner workings are not fresh in my mind. Any help is appreciated.

Also, please don't give me the old, "Don't use Regular Expressions to parse HTML..." speech. I know.

By the way, this is my old regex that worked properly (the input was different though of course):
 `(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your regex for some reason. Such as the ?=/, but it seems like you just want to grab the img url? In that case, why not match ~(http://minotar.net/avatar/.+?)"~

Comment: Also, if you use / as your delimiter, shouldn't you escape / when you use it again? Such as /avatar/ should be \/avatar\/. That's why I use ~ as the delimiter

Comment: For future reference, this site is a good place to test out Regex in realtime: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @GarethParker It's a positive lookahead. If you go to regexr.com, input my regex and the sample HTML string I provided, and check the global box, it matches everything I want. But PHP doesn't match it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the /'s in the regex code.

-EDIT-

ascii-lime also pointed out that you can change the delimiter to another non-alphanumeric character(with exceptions). To do this change the / at the start and end of the expression to the character of choice. Example:

```
'/.+\/regex.com\/index.html+./'
```

to

```
'!.+/regex.com/index.html+.!'
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks. For some reason Regexr.com doesn't require you to escape them.

Comment: Just something I remembered from class. I fixed your code and ran it on http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php no problem.

Comment: @DC_ That's because there is nothing special about `/`. It's just the delimiter you are using (to signify the start and end of your expression). You could use another symbol if you wanted too.

Comment: @DC_ `#` is a fairly common as a delimiter, but `/` is by far the most commonly used one. If you change your delimiter you don't need to escape the `/`s: `$regex = '#(?<=/avatar/).+?(?=/)#';`

Comment: @ascii-lime I don't think it's just a delimiter - I'm matching the `/`'s in the URL. Changing it to # doesn't work.

Comment: @ascii-lime So changing the / at the start and end of the end of the regex string will change the delimiter or do you have to change it somewhere else(in code or config file)?

Comment: @RMDan Right! You can pick a different delimiter on every PHP regex if you want. It can be any character that isn't a letter, number, whitespace, or backslash (``\``). [See the PHP Manual page on Delimiters for more info :)](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: @ascii-lime Oh wait - I see what you're saying now. The delimiters weren't the problem though, it was the unescaped `/`'s. This is the correct regex: `/(?<=\/avatar\/).+?(?=\/)/`

Comment: @DC_ Both do the same thing :) The `/`s don't need to be escaped if you pick a delimiter that isn't in your regex. Both work perfectly fine though.

Comment: @DC_ yes, that string will work if you use the / as the delimiter. You could also use this with no issue: !(?<=/avatar/).+?(?=/)! Now that ascii-lime shown us how to change the delimiter I wont have as many issues with urls in regex php.

Comment: @RMDan Learn something every day :)